# Unable to register crystl32.ocx

Tags: windows-7, vb6, regsvr32, dllregistration

I keep getting the error message when I try to launch VB6 application on my Windows 7 system

```
Component 'crystl32.ocx' or one of its dependencies not correctly registered: a file is missing or invalid
```

I have tried a lot of options to register this like first copying `crpe32.dll` and `implode.dll` into `System32` and `syswow64` folders and then using `regsvr32.exe` to register but that gives me error message

```
The module 'crystl32.ocx' failed to load. Make sure the binary is stored at the specified path or debug it to check for problems with the binary or dependent .DLL files. THe specified module could not be found.
```

I can browse to `C:\Windows\System32` and `SysWow64` and see the files there.

Recently I did installation of `Oracle 11g`, un installation of `Oracle 9g`, played around with `Environment variables` too so is that causing the issue? Before that, same application was working fine without any error message.

Comment: *The specified module could not be found.* Looks like you're still missing a DLL. Have you stuck it through a Hex Editor to look at the list of DLLs it references?

Comment: If it's any help, I did find [this](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-registered/ocx/windows/learning-tree/multimedia-cbt-training-learntrack/crystl32-ocx/).

Comment: Have you tried to register with admin privileges on console?

Comment: @Korsakof yes. got same error

Comment: Have you rebooted the machin after?In case not, you should.
Also Have you registered in this path "CD C:\Windows\System32"?

Comment: @Korsakof yes restarted and registered in System32 as well. I get the same error message i.e `The module failed to load`

Comment: Have you checked all the dependencies?
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28431512/component-CRYSTL32-OCX-or-one-of-its-dependencies-not-correctly-registered-a-file-is-missing-or-invalid.html

Comment: Try from a 64 bit program `C:\Windows\Syswow64\regsvr32  C:\Windows\Syswow64\crpe32.dll`. From a 32 bit program (like cmd in syswow64) `regsvr32 crpe32`. To register a 64 bit file from 32 bit `C:\windows\sysnative\regsvr32 C:\Windows\Sysnative\crpe32.dll`. `Sysnative` is what 32bit programs use to access `c:\windows\system32` without being redirected to `c:\windows\syswow64`.  Windows redirect calls based on bitness of the starting app and the running app.

Comment: If the OCX came with a .DEP file that ought to list all its dependencies. Check your original installation media. If this started happening after your Oracle uninstall, possibly that had removed some dependency. You might check the files in the Oracle install and see if that turns up anything useful. Last thought - if this works on ANY machine, see if you can use Process Explorer or similar to see what dependencies are loaded when it works. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

try this one: make sure these files are found inside C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64 folder:

crystl32.ocx,
crviewer.dll,
implode.dll,
crpe32.dll

then use the Regsvr32.exe **WITHIN** the C:\WINDOWS\SYSWOW64 folder and NOT THE ONE found on C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 folder with this command:

regsvr32 c:\Windows\SysWow64\crystl32.ocx

Answer (score 0):

If this works on ANY OTHER machine, see if you can use Process Explorer or similar to see what dependencies are loaded when it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ANY of external `OCX` controls, you need to move all associated files. For me and `crystl32` there were a lot more in `system32`. How i found them?

1. Go to `system32`
2. Set details view for this folder
3. Right click on column header (Any will work)
4. Click `More`
5. Find something on this list that could show you connection between your `ocx` and other required files*
6. Copy all those files to system32
7. Try register original one

*For me it was either `Description` or `Company` depends on OCX I wanted to register.